# what's a good angular-design-pattern for step by step repeatable flows?

Tags: angularjs

Our angular application has a flow-
step1-step2-step3. In step3 there is an option to start a new flow from step1.
It it important no data is mixes between the flows. 
What is the best design for such a flow?
The steps share data, so I suspect I need a controller, but how do I make sure it is initialised each iteration (I don't want to write a "init" method)

Answer (score 1):

I would write each step as a directive and pass the overall state in through two-way binding. The state would be held in the controller's scope and would need to be reset when coming back to the first step after completing the flow.

For example, you could have a "Start over" button at the end of the flow, which clears the state from the scope. The controller would see that and immediately display the first step, free of all old data. If you use ngIf, the directives will initialise cleanly when allowed to show.

Example controller template:

```
<div>
    <div myflow-step1="yourData" ng-if="!yourData.step || yourData.step == 1"></div>
    <div myflow-step2="yourData" ng-if="yourData.step == 2"></div>
    <div myflow-step3="yourData" ng-if="yourData.step == 3"></div>
</div>
```

And the "Start over" button in step 3 would just do:

```
$scope.yourData = {};
```

Comment: then maybe the 3 steps should be wrapped with a directive + ngIf (on the wrapped)? That way everything will initialise automaticlly? My concern is that manual clean in scope can "forget" to clear some fields...

Comment: If you keep your whole data in one scope object, you can just do $scope.yourData = {}; and the old data is gone. Nothing to forget. Also, the inner scopes of the directives get destroyed automatically when ngIf equates to false.

Comment: What I decided to do is             $route.reload();
Because- 1. it reloads the template configured in the $routeProvider; 2. it creates a new scope (reloads controller, which initalizes and sets "step1" as active- which is what I wanted). What do you think?

Comment: That's actually a good solution, why didn't I think of that? :)
You should answer you own question with that solution.